# How to find the 6th highest value in a list

Tags: c#, sorting

I am new to C# so please be gentle. I am using c# in a transformation script and I need to find the 6th highest value in a list such as this

```
57
50
90
60
57
93
100
53
73
87
77
```

I can change it into  a string array by using

```
string [] arr = args.Content.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray());
```

but I get lost from there

Thanks
Paul Fone

Comment: What data type us your list? (Int array, string array, string, etc.)

Comment: Convert each one to number, put in array, sort array, take the sixth element - which part are you struggling with?

Comment: @user1734455 you'll have to be more specific about what you are struggling with if you want anyone to help you.

Comment: I am struggling with the whole lot  - need code from scratch

Comment: Btw, your sample could be better since the 6th highest is also the 6th lowest.

Comment: OT: This question kinda reminded me /r/gonewild.[18+] :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort it numerically  you have to convert the strings to `int` first, then you can use `Enumerable.OrderByDescending` and  `Enumerable.Skip(5).Take(1)`:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = arr.Select(int.Parse)
                           .OrderByDescending(i => i)
                           .Skip(5).Take(1);
Console.Write("Sixth element is: " + ints.First());
```

or create a new list from the ordered sequence at then use `Enumerable.ElementAt`:

```
List<int> ints = arr.Select(int.Parse).OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList();
Console.Write("Sixth element is: " + ints.ElementAt(5));
```

(omitted exception handling for invalid format or too little items)

Comment: I think you should use .Reverse() after the OrderBy method to get the 6th highest. In the example provided in the question 73 happened to be both the 6th highest and the 6th lowest number.

Comment: Good point, thanks, corrected.

Comment: Thankyou but I will try answer3

Comment: @User: are you still using. NET 2? Otherwise you have Linq. You might need to add using System.Linq in your file. However, remember to accept the best answer(or what you have chosen).

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ, like this:

```
var res = args.Content.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray())
     .Select(int.Parse)
     .OrderBy(x=>x)
     .Skip(5)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The only problem with all these linq solutions is that bad input can throw a wrench in it.

Comment: Thankyou but I will try answer3 as I don't have LINQ

Answer (score 0):

To start, you need to first convert your numbers into an `int[]`. You can do that like this:

```
string[] strs = args.Content.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray());
int[] ints = new int[strs.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length; i++)
    ints[i] = int.Parse(strs[i]);
```

Then you can use `Array.Sort(ints);` to actually sort them. Then, you use `int result = ints[ints.Length - 6 - 1];` to get the sixth-to-last element in the sorted array: that is, the 6th highest element.

The completed code looks like this:

```
string[] strs = args.Content.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray());
int[] ints = new int[strs.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length; i++)
    ints[i] = int.Parse(strs[i]);

Array.Sort(ints);

int result = ints[ints.Length - 6 - 1];
```

Comment: Thankyou for your time. I tried this as follows but I get a Custom script error

Comment: Thankyou for your time. I tried this but I get a Custom script error

Comment: @user1734455 How are you running this code?

Comment: C# script is used to transform web pages and extracted data within a program called Visual Web ripper.  The help file states -

Comment: C# and VB.NET Scripts

A content script must have one method as shown below.



01.public   static   void  ScriptMethod(WrContentScriptArguments args)    
02.{    
03.     try    
04.    {               
05.    }    
06.     catch (Exception exp)    
07.    {    
08.        args.WriteDebug(exp.Message);    
09.    }    
10.}   

public static void ScriptMethod(WrContentScriptArguments args) 

The script method ScriptMethod must have this exact name and signature, so change only the method body.

Comment: Thanks again for your time - I found your code was missing                           if (strs[i].Length == 0)                  all works OK now